# Xamarin Android: create folder on PublicDirectory for my app

Tags: xamarin.android

I have a funny but tricky problem with Android. In my Xamarin Forms project I want to create a folder where I store all files generated from my app so I can access to them easily via a FileManager.

Until this morning in Android I used

```
Environmentstring path = Android.OS.Environment.
                         GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                             Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDocuments).ToString();
Environmentpath += "/MyApp";
EnvironmentDirectory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

I added some new components to my solutions and now everything is denied.

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/storage/emulated/0/Documents/MyApp" is denied.

I changed then the **AndroidManifest.xml** like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_GSERVICES" />
</manifest>
```

But now I can't create anything in this folder. Just for example, I'm using the same code in other my application and the result is

[image: FileManager example]

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: On wich device do you test? If you test on Android 6 hardware check the rights in the app manager. Sometimes the write_external storage is ignored and has to be set in the app manager.

Comment: My device is a Cubot phone with Android 6. I think `write_external` is ignored but I don't know how to set it.

Comment: open the appmanager and navigate to your app. click on it and then to permissions. now swich on the storage. hop that helps. have the same problem on a s7.

Comment: sorry, appmanager in Visual Studio or on the device?

Comment: on your android device

Answer (score 1):

As [user1230268](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42029474/xamarin-android-create-folder-on-publicdirectory-for-my-app#comment71281573_42029474) stated try to go to your app manager on your device and enable the permissions. For me it was

Settings > Device > Apps > YourAppName > Permissions > Storage

Enable it and you should be good to go.